# C++ Design: how to design the "can perform or can be " relationship in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am new to C++ design programming. I am having some problems with how to design my code.
I have a class, called A, which contains an array and some basic array functions, such as set, get, and print. I also want to have one more for a function like sort. However, I want to be able to provide the functionality to choose a type.  For example:

```
a.sort.quick()
```

or

```
a.sort.merge()
```

how can I achieve this and is there any other better way of doing so?

Comment: Usually containers don't have algorithms like this, usually algorithms and containers are separate, and work together, where the algorithm has a function interface, and the container is a parameter (or two iterators).

Comment: you mean that Sort class should be different and in that we can define that different different algo and it can take a generic parameter to sort.?

Comment: I mean like `std::sort(a.begin(), a.end())`

Comment: Thanks Mooing.than how to provide the functionality to choose the algo. will it be write design to pass another parameter to the sort function for type or any other better way?

Comment: `sorts::mergesort(a.begin(), a.end())`, `sorts::quicksort(a.begin(), a.end())`?

Comment: got your point. thanks! 
one more question should all the "can be" relationship should be design like this?

Comment: In general, a class should have only the members required to maintain it's constraints (no memory leaked, count is accurate, exception safety, etc.  For example: `std::vector`.  As an example of what NOT to do: `std::string`).  Things that modify the data usually go in standalone functions or namespaces.

Comment: can you please point me out some link for quick and best understanding for proper design programming. as i couldn't understand much from your above statement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: one more thing that by this way sorts::mergesort(a.begin(), a.end()) all sorting will e under their name, they will not be under one roof. like sort.merge() . does this way not look some unorganized?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to be able to achieve this is to have a class that contains those methods, and create an instance of those classes. For example:

```
class Sort {
    public:
        sortMethodA() {}
        sortMethodB() {}
        // etc...
};

class A {
    public:
        Sort sort;
};

A a;
a.sort.sortMethodA();
```

edit: you can also make something like:

```
a.sort(QUICK);
```

meaning you could have an enum and sort based on what you pass

Comment: but if array is the member of class A and private too, how to pass that to sort? what will be the data member of class sort? please bear with me

Comment: instead of making it outside the class like i did, make Sort go inside class A

Comment: you mean define class sort as a subclass of class A.